# Http get response utf-8

Tags: java, http, servlets, utf-8

I have following code. When i get the response, it's characters are faulty. i want to get the response with "UTF-8". How and where can i write that in my code below?

Thanks

---

URL httpPost = new URL(url);

```
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) httpPost.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.getOutputStream().write(params.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        connection.getOutputStream().flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            response.append(inputLine);

        }

        try {

            String responseFromServer = response.toString();

            dealsResponse = Utils.mapper.readValue(responseFromServer, GetDealsResponse.class);

        } finally {
            in.close();

        }
```

Comment: Obtain an HTTP trace. Maybe the response is indeed broken? In which case you'll need to fix the server.

Comment: i trace the inputline it's like this. {"message":"Sunucu hatas?","success":false}

Comment: A raw HTTP trace is needed.

Answer (score 0):

connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");